# how to use python libirary pyzwcad to automate tasks and draw in ZWcad?

Tags: python, autocad, zwcad

I was working on a project to create a tool that helps engineers to automate drawing tasks and as my company using ZWcad instead of Autocad I found myself obliged to use pyzwcad but I could not find enough information about it in one place or I was not searching in the correct places since I'm a beginner programmer and I need to gather all the Data I collect in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to import pyzwacad

```
from pyzwcad import *
```

or just import the used methods

```
from pyzwcad import ZwCAD, ZCAD, APoint, aDouble
```

my preferred way to automate tasks using API is to let the user start the program before using the tool.

so we now need to define the cad object

```
acad = ZwCAD()
```

in the next paragraphs I will summarize some of pyzwacad methods I use in my project.

1. Add line type in the current drawing file.

   ```
   def G_add_line_typ(ltyp_name, acad):
       line_type_found = False
       for ltyp in acad.doc.Linetypes:

           if ltyp.name == ltyp_name:
               line_type_found = True
       if not line_type_found:
           acad.doc.Linetypes.Load(ltyp_name, "ZWCADiso.lin")
   ```
2. Draw square:

   X_coo: is the X coordinate for the center point of the square shape.

   y_coo: is the Y coordinate for the center point of the square shape.

   we need to make an array/list for square points coordinate for example first point will take the first two positions in the list so

   list[0] is the first point X coordinate and

   list[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAkcS.png) is the first point Y coordinate.

   ```
   def draw_sqr(acad, X_coo, y_coo, d, w, n_color):
       sqr_pts = [X_coo - (d / 2), y_coo + w / 2, X_coo - (d / 2), y_coo - w / 2, X_coo + (d / 2), y_coo - w / 2, X_coo + (d / 2), y_coo + w / 2, X_coo - (d / 2), y_coo + w / 2]
       sqr = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(aDouble(sqr_pts))
       sqr.color = n_color
       # shape color is an integer from color index 1 for red.
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

3- Add Circle:

```
# add insertion point
x_coo = 50
y_coo = 50
c1 = APoint(x_coo, y_co)
radius = 500
circle= acad.model.AddCircle(c1, radius)
```

4- Rotate object:

```
# add base point
x_coo = 50
y_coo = 50
base_point= APoint(x_coo, y_co)
r_ang = (45 * np.pi) / 180
object.Rotate(base_point, r_ang)
# object is refering to the object name it could be difrent based on your code
```

5- Add text:

```
# add insertion point
x_coo = 50
y_coo = 50
pttxt = APoint(x_coo, y_coo)
txt_height = 200 # text height
text = acad.model.AddText("text string", pttxt, txt_height)
```

6- Change text alignment:

```
# first we need to sort the current insertion point for the exist text object as it will be reset after changing the alignment.

old_insertion_point = APoint(text.InsertionPoint)
# text is refering to text object name it could be difrent based on your code


text.Alignment = ZCAD.zcAlignmentBottomCenter

# modify the text insertion point as the above step automaticaly reset it to (0, 0)
text.TextAlignmentPoint = old_insertion_point
```

7- Add rotated dimension line:

we need to define 3 points

start point, end point and dimension text point,also we should use math lib to use the radians method

```
import math
acad = ZwCAD()
st_dim = APoint(0, 0)

end_dim = APoint(100, 30)

text_dim = APoint(50, 15)

dim_line = acad.model.AddDimRotated(st_dim, end_dim, text_dim, math.radians(30))

acad.Application.ZoomAll()
```

the above code could be used to add liner dimention line by use 0 in angle place for horizontal dimension or math.radians(90) for vertical dimensions.

8- Add Aligned dimension line:

same as above but without using rotation angle.

```
acad = ZwCAD()
st_dim = APoint(0, 0)

end_dim = APoint(100, 30)

text_dim = APoint(50, 15)

dim_line = acad.model.AddDIMALIGNED(st_dim, end_dim, text_dim)
```

9- override existing dimension line text:

```
dim_line.TextOverride = "new text"
```

"dim_line" is referring to the wanted dimension line object name.